# AChartEngine not displaying Y and X axis values and label count

Tags: java, android, date, achartengine

I'm trying to build a line chart with this engine. It is drawing like I expected, except that is not displaying my values. I can't see where is my error, please help me. This is the code:

```
private View getLineChart(Context context)
{
    List<Double> weights = App.helper.getWeights();
    List<String> weightsDate = App.helper.getWeightsDate();

    for(int x = 0; x < weights.size(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = x + 1; x < weights.size(); x++)
        {
            if(weights.get(x) > weights.get(y))
            {
                double temp = weights.get(x);
                weights.set(x, weights.get(y));
                weights.set(y, temp);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();

    for(int x = 0; x < weightsDate.size(); x++)
    {
        Date date = new Date(weightsDate.get(x));
        dateList.add(date);
    }

    Collections.sort(dateList);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer xyRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(xyRenderer);
    renderer.setChartTitle("Histórico de Peso");

    renderer.setYTitle("Peso");
    renderer.setYLabels(weights.size());
    renderer.setYAxisMin(weights.get(0));
    renderer.setYAxisMax(weights.get(weights.size() - 1));
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);

    renderer.setXTitle("Data");
    renderer.setXLabels(weights.size());
    renderer.setXAxisMin(dateList.get(0).getTime(), 0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(dateList.get(dateList.size() - 1).getTime(), 0);       
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(12);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);  
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#5f5f5f"));          
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);

    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Peso");

    for(int x = 0; x < weights.size(); x++)
    {
        series.add(weights.get(x), dateList.get(x).getTime());
    }

    dataset.addSeries(series);

    View view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, renderer);

    Log.d("WEIGHT_TEST", String.valueOf(weights.get(0)));

    return view;
}
```

I'm calling this on my onResume method. The chart is drawn, but the min and max values are not respected, and the label count isn't respected too. Also, is there a way I can show dd/MM/yyyy dates on the X axis?